# I am unable to access the id of a newly saved instance of model to be used in processing another form within the same page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a page with two different forms and one submit button. One form creates the title and the other form creates the questions that will be placed under the title. The title is linked to the question with a one to many relationship. However, when I submit the form, the title get created but I can't access the title so that my other form can use it in the view. The forms are created like so:

```
        6     class DeckForm(ModelForm):
        7     title = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(
        8                                     attrs={'class': 'title',
        9                                            'placeholder': 'Title'}),
       10                                     label='')
       11     subject = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(
       12                                     attrs={'class': 'subject',
       13                                            'placeholder': 'Subject'}),
       14                                     label='')
    ⚠  15     class Meta:
       16         model = Deck
       17         fields = ['title', 'subject']
       18 
    ⚠  19 class CardsForm(ModelForm):
    ⚠  20     class Meta:
       21         model = CardsQuestion
       22         fields = ['questionText', 'answerText']
       23 
       24 CardsFormset = formset_factory(CardsForm, extra=1)
    ~                                                               

And they are managed in the view like so:

⚠  27 class QuestionsView(TemplateView): 
   28     template_name = "cards/questions.html" 
   29                                
   30     def get(self, *args, **kwargs): 
⚠  31         NewCardsForm= CardsFormset() 
⚠  32         NewDeckForm= DeckForm() 
   33         return self.render_to_response( 
   34             {'CardsFormset': NewCardsForm, 
   35              'DeckForm': NewDeckForm})
⚠  36     def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
⚠  37         NewDeckForm= DeckForm(data=self.request.POST)
⚠  38         NewCardsForm= CardsFormset(data=self.request.POST)
   39         if NewDeckForm.is_valid():
⚠  40             newDeck = NewDeckForm.save(commit=False)
   41             newDeck.creator = self.request.user
   42             newDeck.save()
   43             if NewCardsForm.is_valid():
   44                 for card in NewCardsForm:
   45                     card.save(commit=False)
   46                     **card.deck = newDeck**
   47                     card.save()
   48                 return HttpResponseRedirect("dashboard")
   49         return self.render_to_response(
   50             {'CardsFormset': CardsForm,
   51              'DeckForm': DeckForm})
```

I have bolded the area I think is causing me issues. The error that is being thrown is this
**null value in column "deck_id" violates not-null constraint**

Could you advice me on what needs to be done in order to be able to rectify that error? Much thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poster here. It was solved through by getting cleaned_data of each form within the formset and then using create command like so:

```
    if new_card_form.is_valid():
        for form in new_card_form:
            question = form.cleaned_data.get('questionText')
            answerText = form.cleaned_data.get('answerText')
            empty = bool(form.cleaned_data.get('questionText'))
            print(empty)
            print(question)
            if empty is True: 
                newCard = CardsQuestion.objects.create(questionText=question,
                                                   answerText = answerText,
                                                   deck = newDeck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method save with commit=False arg just returns an object without saving to database, so if it is newly created it has no id. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

You should save you object first before use it in fk or m2m relations.

Comment: Do you mean the part at line 40 of the views portion? I did save the newDeck at line 42.

Comment: @stressedkid  the problem is probably here: "45 card.save(commit=False)". You call save method on card instance without filling deck field. Even if save method called with commit=False, it performs all checks and throws exceptions if necessary. So you need to add deck field to your CardForm declaration and then in the view assign deck to card instance before saving

Comment: OH! Thank you! I tried by placing card.deck = newDeck into the preceding line but it didnt't work. Could I trouble you to show me how to do it correctly or point me to the part of the documentation that handles this? I am so sorry for the trouble!